# Vertical Text that auto-stretches Div

Tags: html, css

I'm having a big problem trying to build the mock-up below. The dark grey will hold navigation and the light grey will have text running vertically down. The text in light grey will vary but the Div that it's in should always be as tall as the webpage.

Can anyone help at all?

[Mock Up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdrJk.png)

This is what I have so far:

```
<head>
    <style type='text/css'>
        .wrapper{
           position: relative;
           float: left;
           left: 0%;
           width: 100%;
           background-color: #cccccc
        }
        .left1{
           position: relative;
           float: left;
           left: 0;
           width: 332px;
           background-color: #ffffcc
        }
        .left2{
           position: relative;
           float: left;
           left: 0.00%;
           width: 48px;
           background-color: #ccffcc
        }
        .PaneText {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
            white-space: no-wrap;
        }

        body {
           border-width: 0px;
           padding: 0px;
           margin: 0px;
           font-size: 90%;
           background-color: #e7e7de
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="left1">
            left1
        </div>
        <div class="left2">
            <div>
            <img src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/2711/free_icons_for_windows8_metro/128/beer.png" height="48px" width="48px">
        </div>
        <div>
        <p class="PaneText">My Team's Requests / Managed by my direct reports / Processes Completed / Processes Completed / Processes Completed / Processes Completed</p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I'm aware that a lot of the styling is redundant. Just can't see what I've done wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having some mistakes in your css, have a look at this [WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Godinall/27Vb5/)

Also `white-space: no-wrap;` should be `white-space: nowrap;` that's why your text are breaking.

Comment: Your working is brilliant, thank you. But how can we have the background Divs go as far down as the text?

Comment: @HawarKarem Like you said, you don't know the length of the text and it varies, it will be difficult to do so based on your current markup. To achieve that you need to rearrange your entire HTML markups.

Comment: I know this is cheating a bit but do you have any advice on what I could do? This was the main thing I'm stuck on.

Comment: The easiest way would to use javascript or jquery to calculate your text length and apply that to your body.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be a different structure to the mockup that you have provided, however, I have modified your code a little to suit the mockup, as per below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type='text/css'>
      html,
      body,
      .wrapper,
      .left1,
      .left2,
      .left3 {height: 100%}

      .wrapper {background-color: #cccccc; overflow: hidden}
      .left1 {float: left; width: 332px; background-color: #ffffcc}
      .left2 {float: left; width: 48px; background-color: #ccffcc}
      .left3 {float: left}
      .PaneText {transform: rotate(90deg); white-space: nowrap}
      body {margin: 0px; font-size: 90%; background-color: #e7e7de}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="left1">
        left1
      </div>
      <div class="left2">
        <p class="PaneText">My Team's Requests / Managed by my direct reports / Processes Completed / Processes Completed / Processes Completed / Processes Completed</p>
      </div>
      <div class="left3">
        <img src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/2711/free_icons_for_windows8_metro/128/beer.png" height="48px" width="48px">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

As you may notice from the above code, to have a full document height, you must have every parent div set to 100% height (including all the way up to the <html> element).

You had a couple of HTML errors as well which may have been hindering your efforts.

Comment: Sorry about that. Appreciate the correct structure.